# O que significa KWARGS no Python?

Tags: python, funções, argumento

Eu sei que, no Python, podemos definir em uma função algo parecido com o que chamam por aí de "named parameters", ou seja, "parâmetros nomeados".

```
def my_func(**kwargs):
    pass

my_func(nome="Stack Overflow", linguagem="Português")
```

Não sei se a minha definição de "parâmetros nomeados" realmente é o mesmo objetivo do argumento `kwargs` do parâmetro da função (pelo menos, para mim, parece que é; e, se não estiver, gostaria que me corrigissem).

Mas, na prática, o que seria o "KW" desse `kwargs`?

Ele é  um `dict` ou se trata de outro objeto?

Answer (score 6):

Na verdade, como pode ser visto [nessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/1606920), a questão está mais relacionada com a sintaxe de um asterisco e dois asteriscos. Quando você utiliza dois asteriscos, passará um `dict`, como você mesmo citou.

O `kwargs` é só uma convenção para **K**ey**w**ord **Arg**uments (parâmetros nomeados, como você supos), mas a variável pode ser qualquer nome. Caso você queira passar um número indefinido de parâmetros, mas sem nomeá-los, você utilizaria apenas um asterisco, na definição.

Comment: No caso, esses argumentos com um asterísco `*args`, seriam como se fosse as [funções variádicas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) do PHP 5.6?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, eu não conheço muito de PHP pra poder associar os dois, mas, pelo meu entendimento, seria sim. Pelo menos quando usado no def. (:

Answer (score 5):

Como o Felipe comentou, a nomenclatura do parâmetro vem de *keyword arguments* e, sim, tem uma certa relação com os parâmetros nomeados. Com os parâmetros nomeados, você pode definir a ordem que desejar ao invocar uma função ou método. Por exemplo:

```
def fullname(firstname, lastname):
    return " ".join([firstname, lastname])

print(fullname("Anderson", "Woss"))  # Anderson Woss
print(fullname(lastname="Masters", firstname="Wallace"))  # Wallace Maxters
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ei74Kb) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NTGb/0)</sup>

A utilização de `**kwargs` se dá quando você não conhece previamente os parâmetros que a função receberá. Ao utilizá-lo, você está indicando que o interpretador do Python deve coletar todos os parâmetros nomeados não previstos na lista de argumentos, mas que foram passados ao invocar a função/método, criando um dicionário chamado `kwargs`.

```
def fullname(firstname, **kwargs):
    return " ".join([firstname] + list(kwargs.values()))

print(fullname(firstname="Anderson"))  # Anderson
print(fullname(firstname="Anderson", middlename="Carlos", lastname="Woss"))  # Anderson Carlos Woss
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/e67Aol) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NTGd/0)</sup>

É importante notar que mesmo `kwargs` representando um dicionário, a ordem dos valores é mantida a mesma no qual é indicada nos parâmetros da função, graças à [PEP 468 - Preserving the order of **kwargs in a function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/).
 Ou seja, o comportamento de `kwargs` se assemelha mais a um `collections.OrderedDict` que um dicionário comum.

**Mas quando eu não sei os parâmetros que a função receberá?**

Um dos principais usos do `*args` e `**kwargs` é na definição de decoradores. Por definição, um decorador sempre retornará uma função que *representará* a função decorada no contexto em que foi definida. Isto é, quando eu chamo uma função decorada, o que será executado em primeira instância é a função que o decorador retornou, não a função propriamente dita. Como, ao definir um decorador, não sabemos quais são os parâmetros que a função a ser decorada define, utilizamos os parâmetros `*args` e `**kwargs`. Veja um exemplo:

```
def decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Antes de chamar a função", function.__name__)
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Depois de chamar a função", function.__name__)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def foo(name):
    print(name)

@decorator
def bar(number):
    print(2*number)

foo("Anderson")
bar(2)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/GOJmLI) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NTHi/0)</sup>

O resultado será:

```
Antes de chamar a função foo
Anderson
Depois de chamar a função foo
Antes de chamar a função bar
4
Depois de chamar a função bar
```

Perceba que ao definirmos a função decoradora `decorator`, não sabemos quais são os parâmetros que a função decorada receberá, mas ao utilizar os `*args` e `**kwargs` garantimos que todos os parâmetros sejam devidamente passados à função.

Vale lembrar que utilizar os parâmetros `*args` e `**kwargs` não necessariamente exclui a utilização de parâmetros explícitos. Isto é, é possível utilizar em uma função tanto argumentos posicionais, nomeados e ainda os `*args` e `**kwargs`. Por exemplo:

```
def foo(arg_1, arg_2, *args, arg_3=3, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Mas é importante ressaltar que a ordem, neste caso, sempre deverá ser:

1. Argumentos posicionais;
2. `*args`;
3. Argumentos nomeados;
4. `**kwargs`;

Isso pelo fato de o Python exigir que parâmetros posicionais venham sempre antes dos nomeados.

---

Respondendo ao [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70886/o-que-significa-kwargs-no-python/250058#comment145324_70887), o equivalente a fazer `function (...$args)` do PHP 5.6+ no Python é o `*args`, não o `**kwargs`, uma vez que ao fazer `...$args` você obterá um *array* sequencial com os valores passados como parâmetros, assim como o `*args` será uma lista com os valores passados por parâmetros não nomeados. Dado que o PHP não possui parâmetros nomeados, não há equivalente ao `**kwargs` do Python.

---

**Leituras adicionais**

- [How To Use *args and **kwargs in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3)
- [Understanding Args and Kwargs in Python](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-args-and-kwargs-in-python--cms-29494)
- [Documentaion: Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

**Relacionadas**

- [Qual significado do operador ( * ) asterisco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/5878)

Comment: Vou deixar os links para a documentação dos [tipos de parâmetros ](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter) e para a [PEP 362](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) caso alguém queira verificar...