# Por que kwargs não aceita uma keyword? [keyword can't be an expression]

Tags: python

No python existe o [kwargs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70886/o-que-significa-kwargs-no-python), que facilita muito as coisas, quando preciso de nomear parâmetros.
definir quais são os atributos de um elemento que criarei com essa função
Tenho uma função onde o segundo parâmetro eu utilizo um kwargs. Porém, quando passo a palavra chave `class` por parâmetro um erro é gerado.

Exemplo:

```
create_element_tag('tag', 'class'='x')]
```

Saída:

> keyword can't be an expression

Exemplo:

```
create_element_tag('tag', class='x')
```

Saída:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Mas realmente preciso de um atributo cuja o índice contenha esse nome.

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema no `python`?

Comment: Olá, Você não pode passar palavras chaves da linguagem como diz a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).
É preciso mudar de abordagem.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possivel entender direito o que você está chamando de "kwargs" - mas sim, em Python é possível especificar argumentos opcionais em uma função e selecionar os argumentos por palavra chave - isso é o que chamamos "keyword Arguments":

```
def conectar(host, porta=80, timeout=None):
    # [corpo da função]

conectar("http://...", timeout=10)
```

No exemplo acima, usa-se o valor padrão da porta (80) que está na definição da função, e envia-se como segundo parâemtro o valor de timeout - especificando-se esse "keyword argument" na chamada da função. - Pelo que entendi isso é o que você está chamando de "kwargs".

Em nenhum ponto, em Python, você pode escrever uma palavra chave que seja um "statement" como nome de variável - nem como nome de parâmetros.Então, você não pode ter argumentos com o nome de `def`, `for`, `while` ou `class`. Isso é um erro de sintaxe. Ex.:

```
def funcao(while=1):
   pass
```

`class` é a palavra chave usada para se definir classes - portanto é reservada. Alguns dos nomes embutidos (built-in) do Python podem ser redefinidos, e usados como nome de variáveis a vontade - eles em geral denotam classes ou funções, que por mais uso que tenham, não tem um tratamento especial da linguagem: `list`, `id`, `type`, etc...

Agora - Python tem sim um mecânismo que permite que os parâmetros para uma função sejam passados como dados, e não fixados por extenso no código: prefixando o nome de um parâmetro com dois asteriscos na definição de uma função, faz com que quaisquer parâmetros desconhecidos sejam recebidos dentro de um dicionário, que é atribuido àquele parâmetro. Em geral, o nome desse dicionário é `kwargs` ou `kw` - mas isso é apenas uma convenção.

```
In [1]: def ve_parametros(**kw):
   ...:     print(kw)
   ...:     

In [2]: ve_parametros(a=5, b=6)
{'b': 6, 'a': 5}
```

Observe acima que os parâmetros "a" e "b" usados na chamada da função se tornam chaves do dicionário "kw" - que podem ser tratadas como strings comuns, dentro da função.

Só isso ainda não permite que se use palavras chaves na chamada a função -

```
In [3]: ve_parametros(class=5)                                                                                                                                                    
  File "<ipython-input-3-62829ca1a227>", line 1                                                                                                                                   
    ve_parametros(class=5)                                                                                                                                                        
                      ^                                                                                                                                                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

No entanto, há o mecanismo análogo - se você, na chamada de uma função, prefixar um dicionário com dois asteriscos, as chaves e valores do dicionário serão usados como keyword argumetns dentro daquela função:

```
In [4]: def recebe_parametros(a, b, c):
   ...:     print ("a: {}, b: {}, c: {}".format(a, b, c))
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                           

In [5]: params = {"c": 3, "b": 2, "a": 1}

In [6]: recebe_parametros(**params)                                                                                                                                               
a: 1, b: 2, c: 3
```

Então se você usar os `**` tanto para criar os parâmetros da sua função, quanto para recebe-los, pode ter parâmetros com o nome de palavras chave - que serão tratados exclusivamente como strings (mas nunca poderão estar fixas no código):

```
In [8]: def reserved_params(**kw):
...:     if "class" in kw:
...:         print("Recebi o parâmetro 'class': {}".format(kw["class"]))
...:         

In [9]: reserved_params(**{"class": "parametro proibido"})
Recebi o parâmetro 'class': parametro proibido
```

Se você precisa do nome `class` por que sua função, por exemplo, está dando saída para um trecho de html,e  a função já aceita parâmetros variáveis, essa solução deve ser o suficiente - apenas use a palvra "class" como chave de um dicionário na chamada à mesma.
Caso seja uma biblioteca popular que monte html desta forma, o mais provável no entanto é que ela aceite algum nome parecido com "class" que seja convertido automaticamente para `class` na saída da função - nomes como `klass`, `class_` ou `cls` costumam ser usados. Recomendo que consulte a documentação do gerador de html que, me parece, você está usando.

E por fim, esse meio de passar palavras chave não é a melhor solução: for ao caso em que parâmetros automáticos sejam usados, em geral não se deve tentar usar palavras chave como nome de variáveis: os recursos de passagem e recepção de parâmetros dinâmicamente por dicionário se prestam a uma miríade de outras coisas - e, como Python não é muito de exceções, é possível fazer isso. Por que se o nome do parâmetro é passado como uma string em um dicionário e consumido como uma string dentro da função, a linguagem não tem motivos para trata-lo como um nome de variável em um estágio intermediario , e dessa forma lançar um erro de sintaxe: pode-se usar palavras chave como nos exemplos acima, apesar desse não ser o propósito dos parâmetros variáveis.

Comment: Pode especificar o que quer dizer com "especícar"? :)

Comment: "Especificar" - foi um erro de digitação "grande" (comi uma sílaba e inventei uma cento)

Comment: Não quis ser eu a editar. Como isto aqui está um pouco monótono foi uma forma de promover alguma iteração. Aproveito para felicitá-lo pela resposta. Apagarei os meus comentários se você achar por bem apagar o seu.

Comment: Nem -deixa aí! :-)