# no SQLAlchemy qual a diferença entre filter e filter_by

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Existe alguma diferença entre a função `filter` e `filter_by` no SQLalchemy?

Se existe, quando devo usar cada uma delas de forma adequada?

Answer (score 2):

### `filter`

Se você verificar a documentação do método [`Query.filter(*criterions)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=filter#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) verá que ele recebe um número variável de **parâmetros posicionais**. Exemplos de uso seriam:

```
session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.name == 'some name')
session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.name == 'some name', MyClass.id > 5)
session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.name == 'some name', 
                              MyClass.id > 5,
                              MyClass.other == 'teste')
```

Como você pode verificar, `Query.filter` receberá uma sequência com os critérios de pesquisa.

---

### `filter_by`

Agora, verificando a documentação do método [`Query.filter_by(**kwargs)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=filter#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) você já pode notar que ele recebe uma quantidade variável de **parâmetros nomeados**. Alguns exemplos de uso:

```
session.query(MyClass).filter_by(name='some name')
session.query(MyClass).filter_by(name='some name', id=5)
session.query(MyClass).filter_by(name='some name', id=5, other='teste')
```

---

### Qual a diferença entre eles?

A principal diferença é que `filter` trabalha com expressões SQL e `filter_by` trabalha apenas com a igualdade entre  as chave e valores de seus argumentos.

Na prática, `filter_by` só trabalha com comparação de igualdade entre as chaves e seus valores, enquanto `filter` pode trabalhar com [operadores mais versáteis](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators).

```
session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.name == 'some name')
# seria o mesmo que
session.query(MyClass).filter_by(name='some name')

# Não possuem versão compatível usando `filter_by`
session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.id < 5)
session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.id != 8)
```

Isso se comprova quando você olha o [código do método `Query.filter_by`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/c2e8b48a668a7ae7c1467a00e44fb1e4daa660a3/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L1702):

```
class Query(Generative):

    def filter(self, *criterion):
        ...

    def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
        clauses = [
            _entity_descriptor(self._joinpoint_zero(), key) == value
            for key, value in kwargs.items()
        ]
        return self.filter(*clauses)
```

Veja que o `filter_by` por debaixo dos panos transforma os argumentos nomeados em expressões SQL de igualdade e passa para `filter`.

---

### Leituras recomendadas

- [SOPt - Parâmetros nomeados e posicionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250058/6333)
- [Python Docs - Tipos de parâmetros](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter)
- [SQLAlchemy Docs - `filter`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=filter#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter)
- [SQLAlchemy Docs - `filter_by`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=filter#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by)
- [SQLAlchemy Docs - Operadores que o `filter` aceita](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators)
- [Github - Código do `filter`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/c2e8b48a668a7ae7c1467a00e44fb1e4daa660a3/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L1669)
- [Github - Código do `filter_by`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/c2e8b48a668a7ae7c1467a00e44fb1e4daa660a3/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L1702)